# How to force updates / prevent HTML caching of .NET Core web application running on Linux and hosted by an nginx reverse proxy server

Tags: c#, ubuntu, nginx, .net-core, browser-cache

I wrote my web application in C# using .NET Core 5.0 MVC.
I am using routing in the controller to map URLS to and serve Views that use Razor.
I run the application on a Linux server using the .Net core runtime and then host the application using an nginx reverse proxy server.

I make frequent changes to my website and it relies on real-time pulls from my database to get the latest stats to show to the user so it is vital that the views I serve are up to date.

---

**PROBLEM: For some reason, I can publish and deploy new code and it'll show up fine on my desktop but not on mobile or my friends desktops (sometimes it does sometimes it doesn't). I can see new changes if I change the URL slightly like google.com/test to google.com/Test. My paths are not case-sensitive either but all of my SEO/google links have the lowercase/cached version.**

---

After researching, I concluded that the different browsers/apps are caching my HTML/JS/CSS and not getting the latest from the server.

**I have tried the following**:

- Installing the NuGet Package "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" and calling

  ```
    services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
  ```

in my ConfigureServices method.

- Adding the following to my layout file:

  ```
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
  ```
- Adding this to my controller actions that return the views:

  ```
  [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
  ```
- I am hosting my web app server using an nginx reverse proxy server, and I tried adding some of the stuff I saw online to prevent caching with no luck.

Nothing has worked consistently for my Mobile Device (Android running Chrome).

Has anyone else encountered this or possibly know of a solution?

Comment: Did you try adding cache headers in nginx or asp.net core?

Comment: `I concluded that the different browsers/apps are caching my HTML/JS/CSS and not getting the latest from the server.` that's VERY GOOD. It means you don't have to pay for outbound traffic to deliver the same results over and over, you don't have to pay for CPU and RAM to load results the clients already have. And mobile clients don't have to pay for expensive data to retrieve the data they already have.  Even if you disable caching, your ISP almost certainly caches `GET` responses to reduce *their* cost. All web sites use caching heavily. Instead of disabling caching, use sensible values

Comment: @abdusco I tried adding 

proxy_no_cache 1;
proxy_cache_bypass 1; and expires off;

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What do you mean by sensible values? I was just hoping that a database driven site would reflect what is currently in the database.

Comment: ASP.NET Core does **not** cache API responses by default. Somehow you *enabled* caching. By default ASP.NET Core doesn't emit any caching headers. This means the routes, proxies and caches between you and the mobile clients can do whatever they want. They *shouldn't* cache the responses, but as I said, ISPs heavily cache everything. Caching is controlled by *HTTP headers*, not meta tags. Proxies and caches don't parse the content, they only look at the headers

Comment: The [Response Caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-5.0) article in the ASP.NET Core docs explains how caching works in general.

Comment: If you have a PWA using service workers, a new version *won't* be deployed immediately. The first time a browser opens a PWA it will download the new version but *not* apply it. The PWA will be upgraded only after all tabs showing it are closed. This means the client will have to reopen the application at least once. This has nothing to do with ASP.NET Core, that's how Service Workers work. This Google document [explains the update stages](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#updates) and how to check if a new version is pending

Comment: `it is vital that the views I serve are up to date.` on the contrary, if you create an SPA deployed over the public Internet you have to write it so it can handle multiple client and API versions. Some clients will always be older, or in the process of upgrading. That's how the web works. You can [skip the waiting phase](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#skip_the_waiting_phase) by using `self.skipWaiting();` BUT that risks having different tabs or browser windows running different versions

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use **asp-append-version** which is provided by ASP.NET ?

It can be used this way for css/js

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true"/>
```